# Js radio button

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код.

```
    $(function(){

        $('input:radio').screwDefaultButtons({
            image: 'url("images/1.png")',
            width: 173,
            height: 57
        });
    });
```

Все работает, но мне нужно для каждого

```
<input type="radio"
```

Задать свою картинку.
Как это сделать?+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать каждому инпуту id и искать элемент по id:

```
$('#id').screwDefaultButtons({
    image: 'url("images/1.png")',
    width: 173,
    height: 57
});
```

Comment: Да я что то спросил, а потом сам переделал=) 
Но спс=)